# Rails 4 integration tests for multiple Engines with Rspec + Factory Girl (shared factories)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rails-engines

I'm using [Codeship](https://codeship.com) for continuous deployment. My app is setup so that the main app loads a few engines, and the engines isolate specific functionality. Each engine might have various rspec tests related to it's isolated functionality. Codeship spins up a copy of my app, runs a few commands, and deploys the code if everything works. Those few commands need to run all my tests. `bundle exec rake` or `bundle exec rspec` no longer work, as they only run the tests on my main container app (none of the engines).

I ended up created the following shell script that loops through the directories inside my `gems` directory, and calls `bundle install` and `bundle exec rspec`:

```
retval=0
for dir in gems/*/
do
    dir=${dir%*/}
    echo "## ${dir##*/} Tests"
    cd gems/${dir##*/}
    bundle install
    if ! bundle exec rspec spec/ --format documentation --fail-fast;
    then
        retval=1
        break
    fi
    cd ../../
done
exit $retval
```

This works well. All my tests are executed, and it exits with an error if any tests fail. In an effort to see if there was a better way to accomplish this, I tried moving this functionality into a rake tasks. I attempted a couple methods. I used the `FileUtility` methods to loop through the directories and the `System` method to call the same `bundle install` and `bundlee exec rspec` as above. The commands are called, but when it is ran from the rake tasks, their is a problem with the factories. If Engine A calls factories from Engine B, the returned values are `nil`. I'm calling shared factories this way (example from Engine A):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :Model, class: EngineB::Model do
  end
end
```

Sorry this is long winded. To sum up my questions:

1) Is the shell script a good way to manage tests? I haven't ran into any issues with it yet.

2) Do you know why calling that shell script from a rake task causes the factories to return nil values?

3) Do you know why mimicking the shell functionality in a rake tasks also results in the factories returning nil values? (probably same problem as above)

4) Is there a better way to share factories? I've placed all models that are referenced in multiple engines in one engine.